# Validando fechamento de fatura para tipo de compra e venda JavaScript e submeter para uma api

Tags: javascript, node.js, data, lista

Eu sou iniciante e travei na validação de fechamento da fatura.
Construí uma lista nesse formato:

```
[ 

  date: '2017-5-9', value: '59.99', type: 'credit', typePag: 1 },

 { date: '2017-12-17',value: 'R$ 151.08',type: 'debit', typePag: 2 }

];
```

O que eu preciso:

temos fechamento do cartão de crédito no dia 5 de cada mês certo, a parcela sempre cai no dia 10, uma compra ou pagamento feito no dia 2017-01-05 em diante a primeira parcela cai no dia 2017-02-10, no caso se tiver no dia 2017-01-03 ira cair em 2017-01-10.

Ai no caso se o pagamento for débito, ele irá cair no mesmo instante descrito na coluna date.

tentei de varios modos e acabei não conseguindo.

O que eu tentei fazer, criei um for para percorrer, nisso eu verificava as datas se for > 5/02 e se fosse crédito ele adicionava o valor para a fatura do mes q vem ou seja 10/03, e se fosse débito ele já adicionava o valor para o dia, se fosse <5 iria cair na fatura do mesmo mês. fiz algo desse modo

Obs: estou usando nodejs.
E como faço para submeter para uma api ?

Comment: Agora me surgiu duvidas: No caso de crédito, como você sabe que é uma compra e se é o primeiro pagamento ? ... Caso tenha feito uma compra usando crédito na data: **2018-04-02** a primeira parcela seria na data **2018-05-10** correto ? Então o fechamento dessa parcela seria no mês **06**?

Comment: Opa boa tarde, 

O Campo typePag: 1 seria venda, 2 seria compra. 2

Referente " a primeira parcela seria na data 2018-05-10 correto ? Então o fechamento dessa parcela seria no mês 06? " Sim correto uma compra ou uma venda se for > 5 a parcela irá cair no mês seguinte.

Comment: Desculpe a demora, só mais uma dúvida, se for débito e a compra for feita entre **> 5/02** e **< 10/02** iria cair no mesmo mês ? Tenho um exemplo quase pronto, e relendo sua pergunta surgiu essa dúvida.

Comment: se for maior que o dia 5 a fatura ira cair no do mes seguinte, se for menor que 5 ira cair na fatura do mesmo mes

Answer (score 0):

Para mais informações meu repositório:
https://github.com/samaelsimoes/activity-nodejs-with-json-files
fiz direto no server.js

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte.

1. Recupere a data atual em uma variável:

   ```
   let DATE = new Date(); // Data atual
   ```
2. Recupere o mês atual:

   ```
   let MONTH = DATE.getMonth() + 1; // Mês atual
   ```

   Vale lembrar que a soma d `DATE.getMonth()` mais 1, é devido o método retornar 0 à 11.
3. Recuperar o mês anteriror:

   ```
   let MONTH_PREVIOUS = ( MONTH === 1 ) ? 12 : (MONTH - 1); // Mês anterior
   ```

   A condição acima verifica se o mês atual é *Janeiro*, se for, o anterior será *Dezembro*.
4. Recuperar o próximo mês:

   ```
   let NEXT_MONTH = ( MONTH === 12 ) ? 1 : (MONTH + 1); // Próximo mês
   ```

   A condição acima verifica se o mês atual é *Dezembro*, se for, o próximo será *Janeiro*.
5. Agora recupere o ano atual, anterior e o próximo:

   ```
   let YEAR = DATE.getFullYear(); // Ano atual
   let YEAR_PREVIOUS = YEAR - 1; // Ano anterior
   let NEXT_YEAR = YEAR + 1; // Próximo ano
   ```
6. Declare as listas de fechamento:

   ```
   let LIST_OF_CLOSING = []; // Lista de fechamento
   let LIST_THE_NEXT_CLOSINGIN = []; // Lista do próximo fechamento
   ```

Próximo passo é criar o método, não vou explicar passo-a-passo, mas o código está comentado:

```
// Método para fechamento
const closing = () => {
  // Data de fechamento.
  let DATE_OF_CLOSING = new Date(`${YEAR}-${MONTH}-4`).getTime();
  // Percorre a lista
  LIST.map(item => {
    let DATE_ITEM = new Date(item.date).getTime();
    // Data de início
    let START_DATE = new Date(`${( MONTH === 1 ) ? YEAR_PREVIOUS : YEAR}-${MONTH_PREVIOUS}-5`).getTime();
    // Data do próximo fechamento.
    let NEXT_CLOSING_IN = new Date(`${( MONTH === 12 ) ? NEXT_YEAR : YEAR}-${NEXT_MONTH}-4`).getTime();

    /* Verifica se DATE_ITEM é menor ou igual a DATE_OF_CLOSING, depois
     * verifica se DATE_ITEM é maior ou igual a START_DATE, se for
     * adiciona o item na lista LIST_OF_CLOSING, caso contrário, verifica se
     * DATE_ITEM é maior ou igual a DATE_OF_CLOSING, depois verifica se
     * DATE_ITEM é menor ou igual a NEXT_CLOSING_IN, se for adiciona o item
     * na lista LIST_THE_NEXT_CLOSINGIN, caso contrário não faz nada.
     */
    (DATE_ITEM <= DATE_OF_CLOSING && DATE_ITEM >= START_DATE) ? LIST_OF_CLOSING.push(item) : (DATE_ITEM >= DATE_OF_CLOSING && DATE_ITEM <= NEXT_CLOSING_IN) && LIST_THE_NEXT_CLOSINGIN.push(item);

  });
}
```

#### Exemplo funcionando:

```js
let LIST = [
  { date: '2018-2-4', value: '59.99', type: 'credit', typePag: 1 },
  { date: '2018-2-5', value: '59.99', type: 'debit', typePag: 2 },
  { date: '2018-2-5', value: '59.99', type: 'credit', typePag: 1 },
  { date: '2018-3-5', value: '59.99', type: 'credit', typePag: 1 },
  { date: '2018-3-5', value: '59.99', type: 'debit', typePag: 2 },
  { date: '2018-3-4', value: '59.99', type: 'credit', typePag: 1 },
  { date: '2018-4-5', value: '59.99', type: 'debit', typePag: 2 },
  { date: '2018-4-9', value: '234.99', type: 'credit', typePag: 1 },
  { date: '2018-4-3', value: '89.99', type: 'credit', typePag: 1 },
  { date: '2018-8-5', value: '89.99', type: 'credit', typePag: 1 },
  { date: '2018-4-17', value: '71.08', type: 'debit', typePag: 2 },
  { date: '2018-4-1', value: '151.08', type: 'debit', typePag: 2 },
];
let DATE = new Date();
let MONTH = DATE.getMonth() + 1;
let MONTH_PREVIOUS = ( MONTH === 1 ) ? 12 : (MONTH - 1);
let NEXT_MONTH = ( MONTH === 12 ) ? 1 : (MONTH + 1);
let YEAR = DATE.getFullYear();
let YEAR_PREVIOUS = YEAR - 1;
let NEXT_YEAR = YEAR + 1;
let LIST_OF_CLOSING = [];
let LIST_THE_NEXT_CLOSINGIN = [];
const closing = () => {
  let DATE_OF_CLOSING = new Date(`${YEAR}-${MONTH}-4`).getTime();
  LIST.map(item => {
    let DATE_ITEM = new Date(item.date).getTime();
    let START_DATE = new Date(`${( MONTH === 1 ) ? YEAR_PREVIOUS : YEAR}-${MONTH_PREVIOUS}-5`).getTime();
    let NEXT_CLOSING_IN = new Date(`${( MONTH === 12 ) ? NEXT_YEAR : YEAR}-${NEXT_MONTH}-4`).getTime();
    (DATE_ITEM <= DATE_OF_CLOSING && DATE_ITEM >= START_DATE) ? LIST_OF_CLOSING.push(item) : (DATE_ITEM >= DATE_OF_CLOSING && DATE_ITEM <= NEXT_CLOSING_IN) && LIST_THE_NEXT_CLOSINGIN.push(item);
    
  });
}
closing();
console.log('Lista de fechamento: ', LIST_OF_CLOSING);
console.log('Lista do próximo fechamento: ', LIST_THE_NEXT_CLOSINGIN);
```